# Create instance of System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener using string

Tags: c#, reflection, instance, system.diagnostics, diagnostics

I am trying to create an instance of `System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener` using a string, which I am fetching from xml file.

```
Dictionary<string, TraceListener> dListeners = new Dictionary<string, TraceListener>();
string sType = "System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener";
Type oType = Type.GetType(sType);//getting null here
dListeners["Listener1"] = (TraceListener)Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
```

I am getting oType as null above. I can't figure out why, something missing ? Do I need to specify assembly name as well in the string ?

Comment: Type.GetType() requires an assembly qualified name.  Not just the type name but also what assembly it comes from.  Tracing already supports specifying the listeners in the .config file, make sure you are not reinventing a wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create the instance after specifying fully qualified name of the assembly.

Thanks @Hans

```
Dictionary<string, TraceListener> dListeners = new Dictionary<string, TraceListener>();
string sType = "System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
Type oType = Type.GetType(sType);              
dListeners["Listener1"] = (TraceListener)Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
```